# Determine type of serialized object

Tags: java, serialization

I have a need to send messages (requests from the User to the Engine, and responses from the Engine to the User) over a socket. So the flow is essentially

```
       +--------+ serialized  request +--------+      
       | Server | <==== network ====> | Client | 
       +--------+ serialized response +--------+      
           ^                              ^
           | request/response             | mouse/keyclicks
           |    object                    |
           v                              v
       +--------+                     +--------+
       | Engine |                     |  User  |
       +--------+                     +--------+
```

Now, it only makes sense to not reinvent the wheel here. I'm dealing with Java on both sides, so I plan use Objects like so:

```
/**
 * A Client makes a Request.
 */
abstract class UserRequest implements Serializable {
    /**
     * The engine will call request.engineCallback(this);
     * This will tell the Engine what the request is, at which point
     * the Engine will determine its response.
     */
    abstract EngineResponse engineCallback(Engine engine);
}

/**
 * The Engine has calculated a Response.
 */
abstract class EngineResponse implements Serializable {
    /**
     * The User will call response.userCallback(this);
     * This tells the User what the Engine thought of its request,
     * and what happened as a result.
     */
     abstract void userCallback(User user);
}
```

What I'm not following is, in my Server and Client sockets, how will I know what subclass of Request and Response is coming in? I see a situation like

```
Object request = in.readObject();

// now what? How do I know what to cast it to?

// Can I just cast it like
UserRequest request = (UserRequest)(in.readObject());
engine.addToRequestQueue(request); // let it take care of implementation details?
```

My first thought was to just pass everything through over Strings, but that seemed a bit silly when Java provides Serialization. But how do I make sure I know what class came across the wire? For that matter, do I need to know, as long as I only send decedents of UserRequest to the server and EngineResponse to the client?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the `instanceof` keyword provided:

```
Object o = in.readObject();

if (o instanceof SomeUserRequest)
{
  SomeUserRequest sur = (SomeUserRequest)o;
  ..
}
else if (o instanceof OtherUserRequest)
{
  ..
}
```

Comment: So that meta data goes across the wire with the Object? It's not just the data itself?

Comment: @glowcoder:  You, sir, want to read the serialization spec for some deep insight. ;-)   http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html  (and yes, the class metadata goes across the wire so the receiver can load a class and instantiate a new object to deserialize the state into.)

Comment: @Jack, or andersoj, my last piece of code there, `engine.addToRequestQueue(request)` - is that an accepted practice? I don't care what kind of Request you give me, I'm just going to use its callback method in my engine?

Comment: @glowcoder:  Yes, that looks good.  When I've used serialization directly, I usually arrange things so that I know the (super) type of the object before deserializing it; anything else gets too picky.  But yes, knowing the superclass/interface type and dispatching on that is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @andersoj Great. My lawyer will be in touch if it turns out to be wrong. :-) My original question was going to be "How can I switch between String communication and Object serialization. Then it occurred to me that if I can't put it into a Request/Response Object, maybe it doesn't need to be sent across!

Comment: @glowcoder:  Exactly!  And, to make your lawyer happy, you should defensively wrap in a try/catch for ClassCastException, just to make sure things don't go tango uniform and yield plentiful billable hours for the barrister.

Comment: @andersoj The best part is... the REAL answer to my question is in my question. As I was formulating my question, it occurred to me I don't need to know what type of request it is - the engine will just call the callback, and everyone will be happy. I didn't realize that `instanceof` would work, so I'm glad I followed through with my question. (When you write a two-pager, you don't want to just not post it, right?)

Answer (score 0):

For your protocol to be usable with simple serialization, you'll need to have all classes to be sent available on both sides of the connection.

And your `engineCallback()` method will be executed on the server, not be a real callback to the client.

If you want more (like invoking methods on the other side, and passing classes not yet available on the other side), you may want to have a look at RMI (remote method invocation). It is based on Java serialization for the protocol, but adds method calls and the ability to pass unknown classes to the other side to be executed there.